# Optimise Sass Compilation Using Webpack Hot Module Replacement

Tags: performance, sass, webpack, sass-loader, webpack-hmr

**What factors effect compilation performance of Sass files when using Hot Module Replacement with Webpack?**

I currently have a lot of Sass files, organised into multiple directories:

```
├── api
├── assets
│   └── fonts
├── config
├── const
├── decorations
├── functions
├── modules
│   ├── base
│   ├── components
│   ├── generic
│   ├── objects
│   └── vendor
├── themes
├── tools
└── trumps
```

Each directory has a manifest that loads the files within, and my entry point that loads all the manifests as well as all vendor libs is `main.scss`.

Currently I require this file from my application entrypoint (`app.js`):

```
require('../sass/app.scss');
```

Whilst HMR works at present, there is a long delay between saving a changed file and the change being updated in the browser.

My Sass loader:

```
test: /\.scss$/,
loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 4 version', 'sass?sourceMap'],
include: src_dir
```

Devtool config:

```
devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map'
```

**What factors will effect the speed at which HMR updates?**